# How to use microphone in 2 threads?

Tags: android

I'm making an application with voice recognition and output it to the TextView.
To visualize this process, I use [the example implementation](https://github.com/googleglass/gdk-waveform-sample). At the exit, we have approximately the visualization of voice -
[image]

It is implemented as follows:

```
 // The sampling rate for the audio recorder.
private static final int SAMPLING_RATE = 44100;

private WaveformView mWaveformView;
private TextView mDecibelView;

private RecordingThread mRecordingThread;
private int mBufferSize;
private short[] mAudioBuffer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_waveform);

    mWaveformView = (WaveformView) findViewById(R.id.waveform_view);

    // Compute the minimum required audio buffer size and allocate the buffer.
    mBufferSize = AudioRecord.getMinBufferSize(SAMPLING_RATE, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO,
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);
    mAudioBuffer = new short[mBufferSize / 2];

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    mRecordingThread = new RecordingThread();
    mRecordingThread.start();
}
```

And itself background thread for the record:

```
/**
 * A background thread that receives audio from the microphone and sends it to the waveform
 * visualizing view.
 */
private class RecordingThread extends Thread {

    private boolean mShouldContinue = true;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_AUDIO);

        AudioRecord record = new AudioRecord(AudioSource.MIC, SAMPLING_RATE,
                AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, mBufferSize);
        record.startRecording();

        while (shouldContinue()) {
            record.read(mAudioBuffer, 0, mBufferSize / 2);
            mWaveformView.updateAudioData(mAudioBuffer);
            updateDecibelLevel();
        }

        record.stop();
        record.release();
    }

    /**
     * Gets a value indicating whether the thread should continue running.
     *
     * @return true if the thread should continue running or false if it should stop
     */
    private synchronized boolean shouldContinue() {
        return mShouldContinue;
    }

    /** Notifies the thread that it should stop running at the next opportunity. */
    public synchronized void stopRunning() {
        mShouldContinue = false;
    }
```

**Implementation of Speech Recognition is the standard method so I think here it may not make ...**

> Essence of the question

When I turn on program work or a visualizer or recognition but not both, how to run both at the same time?

Comment: Unless that has changed recently, Android only allows a single recorder client at any given time. So if two apps/libraries/threads needs access to the microphone at the same time, that won't work (unless the device adds some sort of custom stream splitter; a few old Sony XPeria devices had this, but it was a Sony customization, and not a standard Android feature).

Comment: Okey, thanks, ill remember =(